# Delete duplicate row with having

Tags: sql-server

I want to remove my duplicate value in SQL Server. So I found a query that can find them, how can I append delete statement to this query to delete them?

```
(SELECT
    DocumentNumber, LineNumber, SheetNumber, Unit, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Lines
GROUP BY
    DocumentNumber, LineNumber, SheetNumber, Unit
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a CTE and a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT Id, DocumentNumber, LineNumber, SheetNumber, Unit,
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DocumentNumber, LineNumber, SheetNumber, Unit 
                                  ORDER BY Id DESC) -- keeps the newest Id-row
   FROM dbo.Lines
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

The great benefit, it's easier to read and to maintain and it's easy to change it to a `SELECT * FROM CTE` to see what you're going to delete.

Modify the `Order By` part to implement a custom logic which row to keep and which rows to delete. It can contain multiple columns(either ASC or DESC) or even conditional statements (f.e. with `CASE`).

Comment: I get this error:Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'IdOrDateTimeColumn'.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
No column name was specified for column 5 of 'CTE'.

Comment: @EhsanAkbar: sure, that is just a sample column. I don't know which column(s) of your table you want to use. Which row you want to keep, the oldest? Which column you want to use to detemine the oldest row?

Comment: .the id with maximum value

Comment: I get this error dear :No column name was specified for column 5 of 'CTE'.

Comment: Do not forget to add `;` before using `WITH`! You can add it at the end on previous line or `;WITH`

Comment: @MegaTron: only needed if it's not the first statement (but included to answer now)

Comment: This is the first statement of my query ,but i get this error again

Comment: dont forget to name your `Row_Number()` as RN

Comment: @EhsanAkbar: sorry, bug included, fixed now. There was no column name `RN`

Comment: Not sure how this is correct this. This will keep a record from duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to do that:

```
DELETE FROM Lines L
INNER JOIN (SELECT
    DocumentNumber,LineNumber,SheetNumber,Unit, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Lines
GROUP BY
       DocumentNumber,LineNumber,SheetNumber,Unit
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1) D ON L.DocumentNumber = D.DocumentNumber AND L.LineNumber = D.LineNumber AND L.SheetNumber = D.SheetNumber AND L.Unit = D.Unit
```

or you can also use table variable or CTE or IN and subquery if  you have a column like ID

Answer (score 1):

Much appropriate approach using `EXISTS`

```
DELETE a 
FROM   lines a 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   lines b 
               WHERE  a.documentnumber = b.documentnumber 
                      AND a.linenumber = b.linenumber 
                      AND a.sheetnumber = b.sheetnumber 
                      AND a.unit = b.unit 
               HAVING Count(*) > 1)
```

Another approach using `COUNT() OVER()`

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                documentnumber, 
                linenumber, 
                sheetnumber, 
                unit, 
                CNT = Count(1) OVER(partition BY documentnumber, linenumber, sheetnumber, unit)
         FROM   dbo.lines) 
DELETE FROM cte 
WHERE  cnt > 1
```

**Note :** Both my approaches deletes all the records for this combination `documentnumber, linenumber, sheetnumber, unit` if it is duplicated